# What is the technical term for this type of ("rough") vocals?

Tags: voice, performing, live

I know that this is not live, I believe this is a scene from a film, so of-course it would have been recorded and mixed in a studio and then edited in to the film.

It sounds so nice and powerful! Can it (vocals of this type and duration, in general) be performed this nicely live, outside of a studio? 
I looked up and viewed many performances of this same song (on talent shows, from all over the world) and even covers (which are not live) but found that none could do it or did it and came any close to perfecting it.

Answer (score 1):

It's called vocal fry, vocal growl, or vocal distortion. Yes, it can sound great live.